# Testing asyn calls throws Unhandled promise rejection in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocking

I´m unit testing an Express function like this:

```
function(request,response,someDependency){
  ...
  someDependency.doStuff(arg1,arg2)
  .then(function(someResponse){
      response.status(200).send({body: someResponse});
  })
  .catch(function(error){
      response.status(500).send({someResponse: 'error');
  });
}
```

In my unit tests (using Mocha), I have decided to mock my response, using assertions inside it, and also to mock my dependency:

An abstraction of my mockedResponse:

```
...
exports.expectedStatus = function(status){
  this.expectedCode = status;
}
exports.status = function(realStatus){
  this.expectdCode = realStatus;
  return this;
}
exports.send = function(body){
  assert.strictEqual(this.realStatus,this.expectedCode);
}
```

and an abstraction of my dependency would be:

```
exports.setPromiseError(error){
  this.error = error;
};
exports.doStuff(arg1,arg2){
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject){
      if (!error)
         resolve({this: 'is', a: 'response'});
      else
         reject(error);
     }});
```

In my unit tests I have a test like this:

```
mockedResponse = require('./fake/assertiveResponse.js');
mockedDependency       = require('./fake/dependency.js');

it('should throw error',function(){
   mockedDependency.setPromiseError(new Error('sorry, not today');
   myLibUnderTest.myFunctionUnderTest(someFakeRequest,
                                       mockedResponse.get()
                                        .expectedStatus(200), <--I´m forcing a failing test here!
                                      mockedDependency);
});
```

But...my assert appears to be [swalled](http://jamesknelson.com/are-es6-promises-swallowing-your-errors/) by the promise and **I get a passing test** with this console output:

```
(node:1512) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
(rejection id: 2): AssertionError: 500 === 200
```

Right now I´m not even sure I´m using Promises the right way...any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should think of a promise as an object that represents data you don't have yet.

Personally most of my experience with promises comes from using jQuery's `$.ajax` method, which actually returns a 'promise' or 'deferred' object of its own:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api.yourdomain.com/yourRoute",
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
          //this is the success callback

    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      //this is the error callback
    }
  });
```

Now, let's say you needed to make a call to get some customer data, and pass that promise into a different method. Again, using jQuery, you could do something like

```
function getCustomerDataPromise(customerID){
  return $.ajax({
      url: "customerapi.yourdomain.com/customer/" + customerID,
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            //this is the success callback

      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        //this is the error callback
      }
    });
}


function parseCustomerData(customerID){
  var customerDataPromise = getCustomerDataPromise(customerID);

  $.when(customerDataPromise).done(
    function(customerDataResponse, responseText, responseObject){
      //this is the success callback of the promise

    }
  );
```

The cool thing about `$.when` is you can actually pass multiple promises in there, and have it fire a callback when all of them finish.

But to get to your original question, you can mock a promise, also using jQuery, like this:

```
function makeMockedPromise(){
  var dummyPromise = $.Deferred();
  dummyPromise.resolve(
      { 
        mockedKey: "Is this mocked data?",
        mockedKeyTwo: "You bet it is! A mocked response"
      }
    );
  return dummyPromise;
}
```

you can read more about this in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Garret. But I think the issue woud persist using your approach. What I understood is that my assert inside my mocked response is throwing an exception and therefore neither fulling nor rejecting the promise...

Comment: not familiar with your frameworks, and so not sure how to help. Do you not expect the mocked response to throw an exception? If that's the case,  are you reading the error message? Do you need to define an error callback?

Answer (score 0):

Not super familiar with Express, but looking at your code, is there just a typo?

I see **this.expectedCode** vs **this.expectdCode**

```
exports.expectedStatus = function(status){
  this.expectedCode = status;
}
exports.status = function(realStatus){
  this.expectdCode = realStatus;
  return this;
```

Answer (score 0):

That was totally a typo, I solved the issue by moving my assertions to a separate method and ensuring it's call using sinon spy. That and using a settimeout to make sure everything gets executed before my assertions with a minimum acceptable time.

Probably not the best...but at least I have my tests running ;)
Thanks for the help.